# Mediafire api call Signature(session token 2)

Tags: api, mediafire

i don't see any post related to generating a call signature(session token 2) using mediafire api.So , here is my question.
I am trying to use the get_info api to get the user information but i am having a problem generating a call signature(Session token 2).

I am reading the documentation given [here](http://www.mediafire.com/developers/core_api/1.1/getting_started/#call_signature) where it says to generate the call signature we need the formula

**The signature = the Message-Digest (MD5) of the 'secret_key' modulo 256 + 'time' + the URI of the API call.**

I have the secret_key and time which i got from calling get_session_token api.The problem lies (i guess) in the URI of the API call.
In my case , i wanted to call the get_info api , so i replace the URI with "**/api/user/get_info.php**" .But i got error saying i have invalid signature.What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

signature = sha1(email + password + application_id + API_Key)

i see that in here: https://github.com/MediaFire/mediafire-php-open-sdk/blob/master/mflib.php

Comment: Hello, I don't think this is the right solution. This is the way signature is generated for "get_session_token" request. For all the rest requests, this is not the way signature is generated. It should work the way with MD5, but it doesn't. If you remember, please write how did you solved this, since it's still an issue.